# Masstransit's Mediator: how to cancel long running consumer execution?

Tags: masstransit

I have set up a Masstransit's [Mediator](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/mediator.html) instance and I am getting responses like this:

```
try
{
    var client = mediator.CreateRequestClient<GetOrderStatus>();
    var response = await client.GetResponse<OrderStatus>(command, cancellationToken);
    // ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{    
    Log(ex);
}
```

My consumer is like this:

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<GetOrderStatus> context)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, context.CancellationToken); // long-running task emulation

        // ...

        await context.RespondAsync<OrderStatus>(...)
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log(ex);
    }    
}
```

On the producer part, if `cancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` is called (by pressing the Cancel button in the UI), the consumer never cancels, so it continues to await in `Task.Delay` and never throws.

1. Shouldn't the consumer cancel the operation?
2. If it is the expected behavior, how can I cancel the consumer execution from the producer side? Intuitively, I thought I could do that by the cancellation token but it seems I missed something.

Comment: I'd suggest creating an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit). For mediator, I would think this should work.

Comment: Issue created: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/2114